# Number of elements in list bigger than average

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a program in Haskell 
that gets a list (of integer) and prints out the number of elements that are bigger than the list's average 

So far I tried

```
getAVG::[Integer]->Double
getAVG x = (fromIntegral (sum x)) / (fromIntegral (length x))
smallerThanAVG:: [Integer]->Integer
smallerThanAVG x = (map (\y -> (if (getAVG x > y) then 1 else 0)) x)
```

For some reason I'm getting this error

```
   Couldn't match expected type `Double'
           against inferred type `Integer'
      Expected type: [Double]
      Inferred type: [Integer]
    In the second argument of `map', namely `x'
```

It could be that I haven't written the logic correctly, although I think I did..
Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These errors are the best kind, because they pinpoint where you have made a type error.

So let's do some manual type inference. Let's consider the expression:

```
map (\y -> (if (getAvg x > y) then 1 else 0)) x
```

There are a few constraints we know off the bat:

```
map    :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]  -- from definition
(>)    :: Num a => a -> a -> Bool -- from definition
getAvg :: [Integer] -> Double     -- from type declaration
1, 0   :: Num a => a              -- that's how Haskell works
x      :: [Integer]               -- from type declaration of smallerThanAVG
```

Now let's look at the larger expressions.

```
expr1 = getAvg x
expr2 = (expr1 > y)
expr3 = (if expr2 then 1 else 0)
expr4 = (\y -> expr3)
expr5 = map expr4 x
```

Now let's work backwards. `expr5` is the same as the RHS of `smallerThanAVG`, so that means it has the same result type as what you've declared.

```
expr5 :: Integer -- wrong
```

However, this doesn't match our other constraint: the result of `map` must be `[b]` for some `b`. `Integer` is definitely *not* a list (although if you get facetious, it could be coerced into a list of bits). You probably meant to `sum` that list up.

```
expr6 = sum expr5

sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

Now let's work forwards.

```
expr1 :: Double -- result type of getAvg
y :: Double     -- (>) in expr2 requires both inputs to have the same type
expr4 :: (Integer -> [a]) -- because for `map foo xs` (expr5)
                          -- where xs :: [a], foo must accept input a
y :: Integer    -- y must have the input type of expr4
```

Herein lies the conflict: `y` cannot be both a `Double` and an `Integer`. I could equivalently restate this as: `x` cannot be both a `[Double]` and `[Integer]`, which is what the compiler is saying. So tl;dr, the kicker is that `(>)` doesn't compare different types of `Num`s. The meme for this sort of problem is: "needs more `fromIntegral`".

```
(getAvg x > fromIntegral y)
```

Comment: probably the most comprehensive message I've ever seen about Haskell, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two errors.

1. Although the type signature in the code declares that `smallerThanAVG x` evaluates to an `Integer`, its code is `map ... x`, which clearly evaluates to a list instead of a single `Integer`.
2. In the code `getAVG x > y`, you are comparing a `Double` to an `Integer`.  In Haskell, you can only compare two values of the same type.  Therefore, you have to use `fromIntegral` (or `fromInteger`) to convert an `Integer` to a `Double`.  (This is essentially what caused the error message in the question, but you have to get used to it to figure it out.)

There are several ways to fix item 1 above, and I will not write them (because doing so would take away all the fun).  However, if I am not mistaken, the code you are aiming at seems like counting the number of elements that are *smaller* than the average, in spite of what you write before the code.

Styling tips:

- You have many superfluous parentheses in your code.  For example, you do not have to parenthesize the condition in an `if` expression in Haskell (unlike `if` statement in C or Java).  If you want to enjoy Haskell, you should learn Haskell in a good style instead of the Haskell which just works.
- You call the variable which represents a list “`x`” in your code.  It is conventional to use a variable name such as `xs` to represent a list.

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained the errors beautifully.

I'm still learning Haskell but I'd like to provide an alternative version of this function:

```
greaterThanAvg :: [Int] -> [Int]
greaterThanAvg xs = filter (>avg) xs
                  where avg  = sum xs `div` length xs

cnt = length $ greaterThanAvg [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: (1) `fromIntegral` is superfluous; it is converting an `Int` to an `Int` in your code.  (2) I would not use a variable `sum'` in this code.  (3) The task in the question is to count the _number_ of the elements that are greater than the average, so you are solving something slightly different.